# Strategies for passing dynamic values from docker run into tomcat jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, docker

I have a smallish webapp running in Tomcat, running in a Docker container built with a Dockerfile based on the official "Tomcat" image from Docker Hub (current tag "8.5.11-jre8-alpine").

I'm going to need to "clone" this webapp, where the clone only has a different window title and header string.  I also need to give the second container a different volume mapping, but I know how to do that.

I'm trying to figure out the best strategies for passing in different string values from the "docker run" command line, so that those strings are seen in the deployed JSP.

I know I can set environment variables on the "docker run" command line.  Past that, I'm not sure of the best ways to get those string values to be read by expressions in the JSP.

Comment: Any trouble using `System.getenv()`?

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, but I wasn't sure if env vars set on the "docker run" command line would be visible at that point. In retrospect, it seems pretty clear they would be visible there.  I'll try that.

Comment: what about a database that both environments can connect to?